# Wrapping C code for use with python

Tags: python, c

I've looked at the Extending Python with C/C++ example so many times but for the life of me cannot figure out what to do with code that is already there. If there is suppose to be a `PyObject *self, PyObject *args` after the call name, then what about all the rest of the parts that are already there?

A small snippet of what I mean.

```
void onNewChannelEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID, uint64 channelParentID) {
    /* Query channel name from channel ID */
    char* name;
    unsigned int error;

    printf("onNewChannelEvent: %llu %llu %llu\n", (unsigned long long)serverConnectionHandlerID, (unsigned long long)channelID, (unsigned long long)channelParentID);
    if((error = ts3client_getChannelVariableAsString(serverConnectionHandlerID, channelID, CHANNEL_NAME, &name)) == ERROR_ok) {
        printf("New channel: %llu %s \n", (unsigned long long)channelID, name);
        ts3client_freeMemory(name);  /* Release dynamically allocated memory only if function succeeded */
    } else {
        char* errormsg;
        if(ts3client_getErrorMessage(error, &errormsg) == ERROR_ok) {
            printf("Error getting channel name in onNewChannelEvent: %s\n", errormsg);
            ts3client_freeMemory(errormsg);
        }
    }
}
```

The full code is here https://bpaste.net/show/f6fd244728de

Looking at the examples I see the use of `PyObject *self, PyObject *args` where the arguments go when naming the call, but if there is already something there what do you do?

When looking at it I thought it would just go like this.

```
static PyObject *
onNewChannelEvent(PyObject *self, PyObject *args, uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID, uint64 channelParentID) {
    /* Query channel name from channel ID */
    char* name;
    unsigned int error;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &name))
        return NULL;

    printf("onNewChannelEvent: %llu %llu %llu\n", (unsigned long long)serverConnectionHandlerID, (unsigned long long)channelID, (unsigned long long)channelParentID);
    if((error = ts3client_getChannelVariableAsString(serverConnectionHandlerID, channelID, CHANNEL_NAME, &name)) == ERROR_ok) {
        printf("New channel: %llu %s \n", (unsigned long long)channelID, name);
        ts3client_freeMemory(name);  /* Release dynamically allocated memory only if function succeeded */
    } else {
        char* errormsg;
        if(ts3client_getErrorMessage(error, &errormsg) == ERROR_ok) {
            printf("Error getting channel name in onNewChannelEvent: %s\n", errormsg);
            ts3client_freeMemory(errormsg);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure I am just doing this in some very weird way when there is a much more efficient way of trying to make a module out of code already here. What can I do to get a module of the code provided to me?